# How to use folium marker on click event to draw other markers on the map

Tags: python, maps, folium

I'm trying to build an app with Python to generate markers when ever I click on an initial marker. I tried using folium but it's not working for me.

I tried editing in the generated HTML file but it doesn't seem to work

```
var map_ae909c763761bdf31c36c841ce820876 = L.map(
    "map_ae909c763761bdf31c36c841ce820876",
    {
        center: [15.0, 40.0],
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
        zoom: 5,
        zoomControl: true,
        preferCanvas: false,
    }
);





var tile_layer_c4c7404e19428fa65bd995467a2df444 = L.tileLayer(
    "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    { "attribution": "Data by \u0026copy; \u003ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e, under \u003ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\"\u003eODbL\u003c/a\u003e.", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 18, "maxZoom": 18, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false }
).addTo(map_ae909c763761bdf31c36c841ce820876);


var marker_f635e6fee0e7bd94c7bb80c0987fbb36 = L.marker(
    [17.0, 42.0],
    {}
).addTo(map_ae909c763761bdf31c36c841ce820876);


var icon_71854da5c79aad9512a5f76335a52cc1 = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon(
    { "extraClasses": "fa-rotate-0", "icon": "info-sign", "iconColor": "white", "markerColor": "blue", "prefix": "glyphicon" }
);
marker_f635e6fee0e7bd94c7bb80c0987fbb36.setIcon(icon_71854da5c79aad9512a5f76335a52cc1);

var markerAdded = false;

function onMarkerClick(e) {
    if (true) {
        // Get the clicked location
        var location = e.latlng;

        // Call the generate_random_locations function from Python
        var randomLocations = [(37.765399062151374, -122.4262010513458), (37.771961656420835, -122.41403182457884), (37.770041968193794, -122.40778410569247), (37.76778755106671, -122.42738339397485), (37.772484352425806, -122.42136521261067)];

        // Generate random locations around the clicked location
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var randomLat = randomLocations[i][0];
            var randomLng = randomLocations[i][1];
            L.marker([randomLat, randomLng], iconColor = 'red')
                .addTo(map_ae909c763761bdf31c36c841ce820876);
        }

        markerAdded = true;
    }
}

//var initialMarker = document.querySelector(".leaflet-marker-icon");
marker_f635e6fee0e7bd94c7bb80c0987fbb36.on("click", onMarkerClick);
```